# Why does this Regex match?

Tags: c#, regex

I have written a regular expression to match the following criteria

- any digit (0-9)
- hyphen
- whitespace
- *in any order*
- length between 10 and 25

> ([0-9\-\w]{10,25})

I am using it to detect payment card numbers, so this works:

```
Regex.IsMatch("34343434343434", "([0-9\\-\\w]{10,25})"); // true
```

But this also works:

```
Regex.IsMatch("LogMethodComplete", "([0-9\\-\\w]{10,25})"); // true
```

What am I doing wrong?

*This is C#*

Comment: try `[0-9\\s-]` because `\w` is word.

Comment: The \w metacharacter matches any 'word character'. You would need to use the \s metacharacter to match any 'whitespace character'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), section  Character Classes.

`\w` matches any word character including underscore, not whitespace.

To match whitespace, you can use `\s`.

To match digits, you can use `\d`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `\w` you can use `\d` which means digit you could use regex like

```
"[\d\-\s]{10,25}" to match your criteria
```

You don't need to check for "words" and this is what `\w` does

Comment: you would need to double the \ and you can put the - at begining or end of class so you don't have to escape it.

Comment: or you can use `@` i just pust regex without escaping ;) but thanks for notice.